# How to get Hulu APIs for Android Internet TV application?

Tags: android, television

I would like to know how I can get Hulu APIs to get data from Hulu for implementing the Hulu Internet TV application.

Is there any such Internet TV provider APIs available for public use?

Answer (score 0):

At this time Hulu does not have a public API. Netflix does though.

Answer (score 0):

Hulu has a [hidden API](http://adammagana.com/2012/09/hulu-hidden-api)

```
curl -s www.hulu.com/api/2.0/video?id=488588 | jq .
```

Result

```js
{
  "video_game": null,
  "video_game_id": null,
  "cr_countries": [],
  "programming_type": "Full Episode",
  "episode_number": 22,
  "season_number": 9,
  "copyright": "2012 NBC Studios, Inc. All Rights Reserved",
  "description": "Dwight and Jim search for a new assistant to the assistant.",
  "is_html5_enabled": false,
  "is_auth_valid": false,
}
```

Comment: It looks like they are encoding the response.